# Json format changed when upgraded to Django 1.3.1?

Tags: python, django, json

I upgraded an app to django 1.3.1 and the json output changed from curly brackets to square brackets.

Before:

```
{
  {
    "code": "KENNEDYS08",
    "duration": 23,
    "preview_frame": 1,
  }
}
```

After:

```
[
  {
    "code": "KENNEDYS08",
    "duration": 23,
    "preview_frame": 1,
  }
]
```

The code that returns the json:

```
output = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

Is there an option for replacing the square brackets [] for curly brackets {}?

Comment: The top version does not match the JSON standards (curly brackets should have key-value pairs not another set of curly brackets). This may be why it changed.  If possible you should adjust your code to take the correct version.

Comment: `output = output.replace('[', '{')`

Comment: That does not make sense. Can you post exactly what data is. (as in a list or a dict). Code snippet would be better.

Comment: out of curiosity: what version of Django were you using before?

Comment: I can't believe Django *ever* produced the first code. It quite simply isn't valid JSON, and would have failed all the tests. Why would you want it, in any case?

Comment: It was django 1.2.5 or 1.2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you have {} in Json is the same as having a dictionary in python ! which means that in a dictionary you always need a key/value ! so the first one is incorrect! if was like that in previous version of Django, thats why the change for the [] version, which is the right one indeed, and should be followed!

Comment: Thank you! The advise was very useful. We will keep the valid Json way.